# Set all properties of same name recursively

Tags: c#

I have an `IsDirty` property of type `bool` on most of my objects.

My base object is called `Client`, but contains several inner collections e.g.: `Client.Portfolios.Policies.Covers.CoverOptions`, each object type has an `IsDirty` property:

- `Client.IsDirty`
- `Client.Portfolios.IsDirty`
- `Client.Portfolios.Policies.IsDirty`
- etc...

How do I recursively set all `IsDirty` properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it truly recursive, I recommend to create an interface that is designed around this idea. For example:

```
public interface IDirtyObject
{
    /// <summary>Gets a value indicating whether this object is dirty.</summary>
    bool IsDirty { get; set; }   // or perhaps get only?

    /// <summary>Sets this object, as well as dirty objects within it, to
    /// the specified dirty value.</summary>
    void SetAllDirty(bool dirty);
}
```

And then in each of your objects, you would implement these something like this:

```
public class MyDirtyObject : IDirtyObject
{
    // (note you can have get and set here even if the interface has only get)
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

    public IDirtyObject MyOtherDirtyObject;
    public List<IDirtyObject> MoreDirtyObjects;

    public void SetAllDirty(bool dirty)
    {
        IsDirty = dirty;

        if (MyOtherDirtyObject != null)
            MyOtherDirtyObject.SetAllDirty(dirty);

        if (MoreDirtyObjects != null)
            foreach (var obj in MoreDirtyObjects)
                obj.SetAllDirty(dirty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless they all share a common base class or interface which defines the IsDirty property, you'll need to use reflection or `dynamic` (C# 4.0 only). The latter is much easier to use, and can be reduced to.

```
foreach (var obj in myobjects) {
    dynamic dynobj = obj;
    dynobj.IsDirty = false;
}
```

Still, if you have the ability to modify your objects, you could create and add the interface to each one. It's better than dynamic, mainly for performance and compile time checking

```
interface IDirtyObject {
    bool IsDirty { get; set; }
}

class ExampleDirtyObject : IDirtyObject {
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
}

foreach (IDirtyObject obj in myobjects)
    obj.IsDirty = false;
```